# $\lim \frac{c_0^k - 1}k$ for $k\rightarrow 0$

Tags: calculus

I am an engineer, not a mathematician and I need your kind help. Let  $c_0\in\mathbb{R^+}$ be a constant positive real number and $k\in\mathbb{R}$ be any real number. How to prove the relation below

$$\lim_{k \to 0} \left ( \frac{c_{0}^{k}-1}{k} \right )= \ln(c_0)$$

the above relation is related to special kind of Seth-Hill strain measures used in material modelling.

Comment: The right side has a variable, while the left side does not. I do not understand what you try to say

Comment: @user27454 It has. The "variable" on the left side is $k$.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake when you put $\lim_{k\to 0}$, it becomes a constant (if it exists). Are you saying that $\ln(k)$ is constant for any real number $k$?

Comment: take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

Comment: @user27454 Obviously that is not what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that for the special case, $c_0 = e$, we have the well know fact 
$$ \frac{e^k - 1}{k} \to 1, \qquad k \to 0 $$
which follows from the definition of $\exp$ as 
$$ \exp(k) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k^n}{n!} = 1 + k + o(k) $$
where $\frac{o(k)}k \to 0$, $k \to 0$.

We have therefore ($\log$ denoting the natural logarithm) as $c_0 = e^{\log c_0}$
\begin{align*}
  \frac{c_0^k - 1}k &= \frac{e^{k\log c_0} - 1}{k}\\
                    &= \log c_0 \cdot \frac{e^{k\log c_0} - 1}{k \log c_0}\\
                    &\to \log c_0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and thank you for the prompt reply